# expectation failed in android during photo upload

Tags: java, php, android

while uploading images to server, it gives me expectation failed error response code 417.

My server side coding is in php, and client is android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

request.getParams().setBooleanParameter( "http.protocol.expect-continue", false ) worked in my case

Answer (score 3):

The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says that this is due to an Expect request header that the server can't meet. Look at the request headers sent by your client application, and see what their purpose is and if they're necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is how i got the solution: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_frm/thread/e178b1d3d63d8e3b

Comment: HttpPost class used in android, adds a header, even if not defined abruptly, hence to overcome an issue, added a code "request.getParams().setBooleanParameter( "http.protocol.expect-continue", false ); "