# android login post method

Tags: android, post, authentication

Hi I'm starting with android developing, and I have to create a login form wich clicking a button, it'll send this: http://www.mypage.com/?U=USUARI&K=PASSWORD. 
Searching in here I've founded a method that Vikas Patidar uploaded nad I've tryed to modify it to my needs. But I think there's something wrong because it doesn't works.
Can you tell me where I am mistaking please?

This is the code 
`

```
public class HttpLogin extends Activity { /** Called when the activity is first created. */ private Button login; private EditText U, K;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    U = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.U);
    K = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.K);

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String   mUsername = U.getText().toString();
            String  mPassword = K.getText().toString();

            tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
        }
    });
}

protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
{           
    HttpURLConnection connection;
   OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;   
        String response = null;         
        String parameters = "U="+mUsername+"&K="+mPassword;   

        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://http://www.mypage.com/content/frmLogin.aspx");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();            
            String line = "";               
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
            response = sb.toString();
            // You can perform UI operations here
            Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
            isr.close();
            reader.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Error
        }
}
´
```

and the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<EditText 
android:hint="Username" 
android:id="@+id/U" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>

<EditText 
android:hint="Password" 
android:id="@+id/K" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:inputType="textPassword">
</EditText>

<Button 
android:text="Iniciar Sessió" 
android:id="@+id/login" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Now I'm trying with HTTP GET method and I got this

```
packge com.android.v3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class v3act extends Activity {
    TextView Tname,Tpass;
    EditText Ename,Epass;
    Button btnCreate;
     String n=null;
     String contentOfMyInputStream1;
     String output = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGen);
        Tname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        Tpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        Epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);




        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Tname.setText("");
            // Thread thread = new Thread();
             String st1;

             st1=Ename.getText().toString();
            //thread.start();

             Tpass.setText("");
             // Thread thread = new Thread();
              String st2;

              st2=Epass.getText().toString();
             //thread.start();

            try {
                 output ="http://www.mypage.com/?U="+st1+"K="+st2;
                downloadUrl(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (output != null) 
            {
                Tname.setText(output);
            }


            }
            });


    }

    public String downloadUrl(String url) throws  IOException{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String response = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url); 

        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength = (int) httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength();
        if (contentLength < 0){
           // Log.e(TAG, "The HTTP response is too long.");
        }
        byte[] data = "8" byte[256];
        int len = 0;
        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
        {
            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
        }

        inputStream.close();

        response = buffer.toString();

        return response;

    }


}
```

but I have some mistake on the line where goes:

```
byte[] data = "8" byte[256];
```

It says: 'Syntax error on token "byte", delete this token'
And if I delete that, I get more errors in reacton.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete

```
The conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

and then the `conn.setDoOutput(true);` already means you are using POST communication.

next.

```
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();
```

change it to

```
        request.write(parameters.getBytes());
        request.flush();
        //request.close();//it is closing prematurly so you will definitely not get any response at all...
```

try these out and let me know if it turns out okey...

if you want to check out try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762968/html-response-from-server/7975884#7975884) which looks almost similar to your conditions...

Might be that will help tooo.... respond.

Comment: did it solve your problem... if yes would you mind indicating my answer as the answer to your problem.. if no... can you please tell me what you have tried,

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your help!
It doesn't worked. If I change the "request.write(parameters.getBytes());" it chows me an error on "write" option: 'the method write(int) in the type OutputStreamWriter is not aplicable for the arguments(byte[])

I think that it's not sending anything to the url I give to call. the problem is that I can't get physical access to the /frmlogin.aspx ...They've told me that with this url: 'http://stats.serhstourism.com/?U=USUARI&K=PASSWORD' , I have to get access with the form. I'm stucked in this.

Comment: btw, I also checked the example you gave to me, but I think it's too complicated for my actual knowledge of android developing :P

Comment: let me write it down for your case and append to my answer.

Comment: i see that you are using post protocol right... or is it get method.

Comment: I think I need Post protocol, because if they give me that URL, it means that I have to send the U=user and K=password via POST...isn't it?

Comment: difference is get uses all the information in one line... likehttp://stats.serhstourism.com/?U=USUARI&K=PASSWORD. where "/?" are the seperaators and things are added to it... but for post ... you just have a webservice to hit and then the password needs to be given in parameters as you used...

Comment: ahmm, so I need to use Get method then?

Comment: try with get method... and i think you have a lot of tutorials... this is exclusive for post... dont use it as it is..let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I'll try now with GET method. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: just let me know if you need help with that one too.. i will get you something really good for your needs... and dont forget to mark this off as done or answer or something... you increase your rep by that too...