# Android login Http GET method

Tags: android, http, authentication, get

Hi I'm starting with android developing, and I have to create a login form wich clicking a button, it'll send this: http://www.mypage.com/?U=USUARI&K=PASSWORD. 
I've started doing it with POST method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141597/android-login-post-method), but I was wrong, and now I'm trying with GET method but I have some problems.
Here is the code:

```
packge com.android.v3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class v3act extends Activity {
    TextView Tname,Tpass;
    EditText Ename,Epass;
    Button btnCreate;
     String n=null;
     String contentOfMyInputStream1;
     String output = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGen);
        Tname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Ename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        Tpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        Epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);




        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Tname.setText("");
            // Thread thread = new Thread();
             String st1;

             st1=Ename.getText().toString();
            //thread.start();

             Tpass.setText("");
             // Thread thread = new Thread();
              String st2;

              st2=Epass.getText().toString();
             //thread.start();

            try {
                 output ="http://www.mypage.com/?U="+st1+"K="+st2;
                downloadUrl(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (output != null) 
            {
                Tname.setText(output);
            }


            }
            });


    }

    public String downloadUrl(String url) throws  IOException{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String response = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url); 

        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength = (int) httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength();
        if (contentLength < 0){
           // Log.e(TAG, "The HTTP response is too long.");
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        int len = 0;
        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
        {
            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
        }

        inputStream.close();

        response = buffer.toString();

        return response;

    }


}
```

[EDIT]
I've changed the '"8" byte' mistake. I put new byte, but it seems doesn't works. Like it's not sending anything to the form.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `"8"` on that line. What are you trying to do there? It should read:

```
byte[] data = new byte[256];
```

Comment: Ok, I've inserted the "8" because it was "" empty, and I thought I had to put any value.

Comment: Even fixin this, it doesn't works. I mean it doesn't seems to make the connection with the url I call

Comment: FIXED!!
After many hours of work I write a new code and it works perfectly.